# Bootstrap Carousel position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I`m trying  to make a E-commerce website using the bootstrap and using the carousel to make products slider . Please check the demo :

[Demo](http://codepen.io/mohamedsamy92/pen/zqLJMy)

The fire code working fine also

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: false
    })
});
```

its works nice , but i need the user see also a part from the next product ( slider ) to know this is a slider and press the next button to navigate ( UX Stuff ) how we can make it [image: ![enter image description here]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKJDm.jpg)
also how i enable the scroll ?

Answer (score 0):

[SimplyScroll](http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/horizontal_manual.html) is one such plugin of jQuery which would be helpful in your case.

With this you can achieve horizontal scroll with partial images.